# Considerations for building Multithread Aggregator with database connectivity

Tags: c#, database, multithreading

I'm interested in building a c# console application that will connect to Twitter's public streaming API and save tweets to a MSSQL database. I wanted to see if anyone wouldn't mind confirming whether I'm approaching this properly.

I'm envisioning that the streaming API connection runs asynchronously on its own thread. When a tweet is received, I'd like to process it against business logic (additional thread) and presuming valid, add it to a tweet-queue (List) that will eventually be persisted to the DB and cleared. Here are the 3 threads for the application

- Background worker listening for the stream's new tweets
- Background worker processing tweets against business logic and adding to tweet-queue
- Background worker responsible for saving the queue every N seconds, then clearing the queue

I believe the tweet-queue variable will need to be static and thread-safe. Maybe the database connection and stream object as well? I'm pretty sure I'd have to lock the thread-safe variables when accessing, do I need to worry about deadlocks? Are there other considerations I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for your help and insights

Comment: I would use a queue for every step. I suspect that you should more threads for listening to the Twitter API, but I do not know it. At least you should put the result in a queue and start listening again. On the next thread, you can do the evaluation and store it to the database. If you really need to, you can still put it in a new queue and store it from another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using MS's native queue collection, would I still need to manually lock the queue object when adding/removing items, or is this taken care of by MS automatically?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wouldn't build a queueing system from scratch having a lot of options in the market which are free or very cheap.

One thread would be listening for tweets and would enqueue it to a persistent queueing solution. Other or many threads would be subscribed to tweet queue to store tweets into your own database storage using your domain layer.

Since you're a .NET developer, [I would check Microsoft Azure's Service Bus service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/), since it's an ideal solution because it supports the producer/consumer pattern or even traditional queues, and in case of topics (producer/consumer), you've a full transactional messaging system which might turn your solution into a reliable infrastructure.

Also, you should look forward for implementing a Windows Service instead of a console application. [Check TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/), an open source framwework to easily develop Windows Services.